# Assembly code automatically running a terminal command

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, runtime-error, nasm

Recently, I wrote a bit of assembly code that asks for the password and if the user enters the correct password as stored internally, it prints out "Correct!". Else, it prints out "Incorrect!".

Here is the code:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov edx, len_whatis
    mov ecx, whatis
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h ; outputs: "What is the password?"

    mov edx, 5 ; expect 5 bytes of input(so 4 numbers)
    mov ecx, pass
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 3
    int 80h ; accepts intput and stores in pass

    mov eax, [pass] ; move the pass variable into eax
    sub eax, '0' ; change the ascii number in eax to a numerical number
    mov ebx, [thepass] ; move the thepass variable into ebx
    sub ebx, '0' ; change the ascii number in ebx to a numerical number

    cmp eax, ebx ; compare the 2 numbers
    je correct ; if they are equal, jump to correct
    jmp incorrect ; if not, jump to incorrect
correct:
    mov edx, len_corr
    mov ecx, corr
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h ; outputs: "Correct!"

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h ; exits with status 0
incorrect:
    mov edx, len_incor
    mov ecx, incor
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h ; outputs: "Incorrect!"

    mov eax, 1
    int 80h ; exits with status: 1
section .data
    whatis db "What is the password?", 0xA
    len_whatis equ $ - whatis

    thepass db "12345"

    corr db "Correct!", 0xA
    len_corr equ $ - corr

    incor db "Incorrect!", 0xA
    len_incor equ $ - incor
section .bss
    pass resb 5
```

**Assemble:**`nasm -f elf password.s`

**Link:**`ld -m elf_i386 -s -o password password.o`

(If you did try to assemble link and run this, you may notice that it checks the password incorrectly - ignore this. It is "off topic")

Then, I ran a test:

1. I ran the code with `./password`
2. When I was prompted for the password, I typed in `123456`, one more byte than the code expects
3. After I hit enter and the code exits, the terminal immediately tries to run a command `6`

What is causing this behavior? Is it something to do with the assembler, or how my computer is reading the code?

**EDIT:**

And, when I run the code with `12345`, the terminal prompts for a command twice when the program closes, as if someone just hit the enter button without entering a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only reading five bytes from standard input, so when you type `123456↵`, your application ends up reading `12345` and leaving `6↵` in the buffer. That gets passed on to the shell.

If you want to read the whole line, use a larger buffer.